# T-SQL Transactions Rollback entire batch or only error records in the batch

Tags: t-sql

I am updating our ERP from our CRM to add a new account. I have a table that has a batch of records to insert. Each record in the batch table will be used to insert into about 20 tables for the new account. I'm using a stored procedure with a cursor. I want to try each insert, If any insert fails all need to be removed. The errors need to be logged to a table and I have a script that does that. The code I have in mind is listed below. How do I know if the transaction is going to post all 15 records in the batch table and if any error rollback the entire batch. Or, if it will post each record from the batch and commit if each of the 20 inserts are successful for that batch table record and only rollback the 20 transactions if the record in the batch table has an error.

```
OPEN @cur 
fetch next from @cur 
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN 

BEGIN TRY 
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
/*INSERT INTO pc.dbo.People --People...*/ 
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH 
error handling sp 
set error flag to a yes 

END CATCH 

BEGIN TRY 
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
/*INSERT INTO pc.dbo.PersonPhone...*/ 
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH 
error handling sp 
set error flag to a yes 

END CATCH 

etc etc through the entire unit of work 
END 

If the error flag is No Commit, else Rollback 

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @some_variables 

CLOSE cur 
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure you need few try catches if you want to rollback entire inserts if error occur. I think it should look like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TRY 
        OPEN @cur 
        fetch next from @cur 
        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
        BEGIN 
            /*INSERT INTO pc.dbo.People --People...*/ 

            /*INSERT INTO pc.dbo.PersonPhone...*/ 
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @some_variables 
            END
        CLOSE cur 
        DEALLOCATE cur

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    ROLLBACK
    -- error insert into table here
END CATCH
```

Let me know if further assistance needed.

> EDIT:

```
DECLARE @ERROR BIT = 0
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    OPEN @cur 
    fetch next from @cur 
    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
    BEGIN 

        BEGIN TRY 
            /*INSERT INTO pc.dbo.People --People...*/ 
        END TRY 
        BEGIN CATCH 
            --error handling sp 
            --set error flag to a yes 
            SET @ERROR = 1
        END CATCH 

        BEGIN TRY 
            /*INSERT INTO pc.dbo.PersonPhone...*/ 
        END TRY 

        BEGIN CATCH 
            --error handling sp 
            --set error flag to a yes 
            SET @ERROR = 1
        END CATCH 

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @some_variables 
    END

    CLOSE cur 
    DEALLOCATE cur

IF (@ERROR = 1)
    ROLLBACK
ELSE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Please test this approach, it should do what you are expecting.

Comment: It seems like if it get's an error then it stops and goes to the catch. And, I want to try all the inserts and log any error. So if it gets an error on /*INSERT INTO pc.dbo.People --People...*/  it goes to Catch, Is there a way that it will continue to the end of the try?

Comment: I have edited an answer, but still not confident it will work, as rollback will undo all what happened, even your log inserts in nested catch. Try insert those logs into temp table, and then after rollback from temp table into real table.

Comment: How would it work if I used a Autonomous Transaction, setting Linked servers 

-- Add a loopback linked server
exec sp_addlinkedserver %server = N'loopback', @srvproduct = N'', &provider=N'SQLNCLI11', &datasrc = &&servername;

-- Set not to start a distributed transaction
exec sp_serveroption loopback, N'remote proc transaction promotion', 'false';

 -- Also enable RPC to call stored procedures
exec sp_serveroption loopback, N'rpc out','true'